# save instances in global variable

Tags: ruby, global-variables, metaprogramming

I need to save all instances of an object in a global variable, so I can access that instances from another object. There is no need to pass them like parameteres.

In my solution I have a mixin with a method that puts the instance in a variable, also I used an open class technique to include that mixin in `Object`, so other objects use that method (and not only ONE class).

```
class Object
    include Favourite
end

module Favourite
    def favourite_it
         #if the variable its not initialized:
         @favourites.class == Array.class ? @favourites.push(self) : 
                                           @favourites = [].push(self)
    end

    def get_favourites
        @favourites
    end
end

 #this class is only an example
class Dog
    def initialize age
        @age = age
    end
end

class Dog_T
    #all instances of this class will be saved in the variable
    def initialize age
        @age = age
        favourite_it
    end
end

class Handler
    def do_something
        #here I need to access the variable with all the instances of favourites to do something to them
    end
end
```

And here is a simple test

```
handler = Handler.new
d1 = Dog_T.new(10)
d2 = Dog_T.new(12)
all_f = Handler.get_favourites

expect(all_f[0].age).to eq 10
expect(all_f[1].age).to eq 12

d3 = Dog_T.new(15)
all_f = Handler.get_favourites
expect(all_f[3].age).to eq 15
```

I tried to do this, but only each instance save itself in a different list (it makes sense because I'm not using global variables yet).

How can I do to have only one list, add the instances when are created and have the ability to empty and manipulate that list from `Handler`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby supports using a class variable in a Module.  You also need a reader method for the Dog_T object to be able to access the instance variable.  Since Favourite doesn't know anything about the object, you will want to use `respond_to?` to guard against calling an non-existent method in the list.  For example, if there were a `Dog_R` class that did not have a method `age` but did add itself, you would get a runtime error blindly calling the `age` method on members of the `Favourite` array.

```
module Favourite
    @@favourites = []          # you can use a class variable in module
    def self.favourite_it(obj) # singleton method of the class
         @@favourites.push(obj)
    end

    def self.get_favourites    # singleton method of the class, see below for usage example
        @@favourites
    end
end

class Object
    include Favourite
end

class Dog
    def initialize age
        @age = age
    end
end

class Dog_T
    attr_reader :age # you need a reader to able to access it
    def initialize age
        @age = age
        Favourite.favourite_it(self)
    end
end

d1 = Dog_T.new(10)
d2 = Dog_T.new(12)
all_f = Favourite.get_favourites

all_f.each do |obj|
    puts "#{obj.class}: #{obj.age if obj.respond_to?(:age)}"
end
puts '-' * 20

d3 = Dog_T.new(15)
all_f = Favourite.get_favourites

all_f.each do |obj|
    puts "#{obj.class}: #{obj.age if obj.respond_to?(:age)}"
end
```

The output of this program is:

```
Dog_T: 10
Dog_T: 12
--------------------
Dog_T: 10
Dog_T: 12
Dog_T: 15
```